# I want to display 000000 to 999999 using textview in android

Tags: android

I want to generate numbers 000000 to 999999 and display it in textview along with common digit "9179". My code works for 0-64 but does not display the prefix five times "zero". Further it only display up to 64. The display should be:

9179000000 9179000001 ... ... 9179999999!

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

int series = 000000;
    TextView test;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    test=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    StringBuilder t = new StringBuilder(); 
    for(int l=series; l<=000100; l++){
        t.append("9179");
        t.append(l+"\n");
    }

    test.setText(t.toString());

}
}
```

Comment: On the same text view?

Answer (score 2):

If you prefix an integer literal with one or more `0` digits in Java, it is going to be interpreted as an [octal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) number - not a decimal number.

The octal value `000100` is 64 in decimal. Don't use the prefix zeroes in your source code. Just write this:

```
int series = 0;

for(int l=series; l<=100; l++){
```

To make the prefix zeroes appear in the text box, properly format the numbers:

```
t.append(String.format("9179%06d", l));
```

Comment: Thanks Jesper. Its working up to 9179000100. I wanted to display up to 9179999999. The program closes when I use :
for (int l=series; l<=999999; l++)

Comment: Are you sure you want to add one million choices to a text view? That will most likely cause an out of memory error. Also, it won't be very useful for the user - nobody is going to scroll through a list with a million entries. It would be better to come up with a different solution.

Comment: Okay. We will see a way to limit the count. If we were to get the value of prefix (i.e. 9179) from user by Edittext then how to get a value using Edittext instead of 
`t.append(String.format("9179%06d", l));`

Answer (score 1):

Just make an Integer sum like:

```
int baseNum = 9179000000;

for (int l=series; l<=100; l++) {
   int myNumber = baseNum + l;
    t.append(IntegerToString(myNumber) + "\n");
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private String getNumberString(){
  StringBuilder t = new StringBuilder(); 
  Formatter formatter = new Formatter(sb, Locale.US);

  for(int l=series; l<=100; l++){
      t.append(formatter.format("9179%06d%n", l).toString());
  }
  return t.toString();
}
```

`formatter.format("%06d", integer)` will give you a number that is 6 character long, using leading 0s if necessary.